# How to get/search hierarchical data from Microsoft SQL Server table for large number of rows and having many levels?

Tags: sql-server, tree, hierarchy

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Server with some columns and it also contains 2 columns for hierarchical data.The hierarchy can be very deep say more than 15 levels and there can be a large number of rows in the table.The table structure is like below:

Table name: tbl1

```
col_a(vachar)    col_b(varchar)    col_c(varchar)  col_d(varchar) ....more columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12              16               Japan           3
16              17               Australia       2
17               0               Panama          1
19              12               CostaRica       4
22              16               Brazil          3
11              12               Bhutan          4
14              17               Japan           2
....more rows
```

If a tree is constructed for this it will look like below:

```
17 (Panama)
|
|__16  (Australia)
|   |
|   |__12 (Japan)
|   |  |
|   |  |__ 19 (CostaRica)
|   |  |
|   |  |__11 (Bhutan)
|   |
|   |__22 (Brazil)
|
|__14 (Japan)
```

Now If I search for Japan I should be shown the below

```
17 (Panama)
|
|__16 (Australia)
|   |
|   |__ 12(Japan)
|
|__14(Japan)
```

`col_a` contains the id value for each row and `col_b` contains the parent id value for each row.

For eg. in the above rows 17 is the first node (it is predefined that the first node has id 17 and I do not need to check if 17 has a parent node or not) and 16 and 14 are the child nodes of 17. Then 12 and 22 are the child nodes of 16 and so on. `col_c` has some text (here country names are given for eg purpose). `col_d` has the level value.

I need to show hierarchical data in tree format. Also search has to be implemented on the tree.

I tried 2 approaches for showing the tree structure. I am able to show the tree but I am not being able to implement search.

Now I first tried to get the data in XML format from a stored procedure and then convert that XML into JSON (the SQL Server version I have does not support `FOR JSON PATH`, but it does support `FOR XML PATH`). So, I tried to get the entire tree JSON and use Ng Prime tree component for Angular to show/search the tree.

For this I tried the following approach in SQL Server:

```
WITH cte1 AS
( 
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d
    FROM tbl1 
    WHERE col_a = '17'
), cte2 AS
(
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d
    FROM tbl1 AS t 
    WHERE t.col_b IN (SELCET col_a FROM cte1)
),
cte3 AS
(
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d
    FROM tbl1 AS t 
    WHERE t.col_b IN (SELECT col_a FROM cte2)
)
SELECT
    cte1.col_a, cte1.col_b, cte1.col_c, cte1.col_d,
    cte2.col_a, cte2.col_b, cte2.col_c, cte2.col_d,
    cte3.col_a, cte3.col_b, cte3.col_c, cte3.col_d
FROM
    cte1
LEFT JOIN
    cte2 ON cte2.col_b = cte1.col_a
LEFT JOIN
    cte3 ON cte3.colb = cte2.col_a;
```

As we do not know how deep the hierarchy can go, I have taken the max level from the table and constructed the above query as a string and then run it with `sp_executesql`. This approach is working but it is failing when the data size and hierarchy depth is very large.

I also tried with recursive CTE but that also did not work due to the same large number of rows and large depth.

So having failed to bring the entire tree data at a time, I tried with a different approach.

In the second approach I am not using any component from any library, and I build a simple component in angular which will show hierarchical lists. In this list I am first showing only node 17 and when the user clicks on node 17, I call the API controller which in turn calls a stored procedure to get all nodes which have parent as 17, i.e., node 16 and 14.

Then when the user clicks on node 16 the nodes with parent node as 16 are returned and shown, i.e., 12 and 22. This is working fine and I have done some work  using this approach. But now the problem is with search. I have no clue as to how should I show the search result in the format mentioned above. How should I get and show the data when the user searches for a text, say Japan (Please see the search e.g. given above)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a dedicated datatype in MS SQL Server to do so. The HierarchyId which is associated to many methods to manipulate tree structure...

To read : [hierarchyid data type method reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16)

But my prefered way to deal with trees is to transform the classical Adjacency List into Nested Intervals...

Read about this method : [Nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the CTE, i'd go for something like this:

```sql
;with data as (
    select *
    from (
        VALUES(12,              16          ,N'Japan'           ,3)
        ,(16,              17               ,N'Australia'       ,2)
        ,(17,               0               ,N'Panama'          ,1)
        ,(19,              12               ,N'CostaRica'       ,4)
        ,(22,              16               ,N'Brazil'          ,3)
        ,(11,              12               ,N'Bhutan'          ,4)
        ,(14,              17               ,N'Japan'           ,2)
    ) a(id, parent, name,x)
    )
,   hierarchy as (
    SELECT  id, CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '_' AS path, name, name AS name2, 0 level, parent
    FROM    data d
    where parent > 0
    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  d.id, h.path +  CAST(d.id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '_' AS path, h.name, d.name, h.level + 1, d.parent
    FROM    data d
    INNER JOIN hierarchy h
        ON  h.parent = d.id
)
select REPLICATE('|_', level) + name2, path, id, parent,name, name2
from hierarchy
--where name = 'japan'
order by path

;with data as (
    select *
    from (
        VALUES(12,              16          ,N'Japan'           ,3)
        ,(16,              17               ,N'Australia'       ,2)
        ,(17,               0               ,N'Panama'          ,1)
        ,(19,              12               ,N'CostaRica'       ,4)
        ,(22,              16               ,N'Brazil'          ,3)
        ,(11,              12               ,N'Bhutan'          ,4)
        ,(14,              17               ,N'Japan'           ,2)
    ) a(id, parent, name,x)
    )
,   hierarchy as (
    SELECT  id, CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '_' AS path, name, 0 level
    FROM    data
    WHERE   parent = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  d.id, h.path +  CAST(d.id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '_' AS path, d.name, h.level + 1
    FROM    data d
    INNER JOIN hierarchy h
        ON  h.id = d.parent
)
select REPLICATE('|_', level) + name, path, id
from hierarchy
order by path
```

The first one is "element-centric" view of your data, ie. it tracks parents for every element, it could be useful in a search or something like this.

The second is regular view of your data. If you index "parent" and "id" properly, the fetch shouldn't be super slow. But with that being said, after you load it, you shold keep it in memory and not hit the db.

Path could be used as identifier and a tree building block

Comment: thanks for answering. I have tried with recursive cte but it is slow. I might use it for showing search results(which is also slow but maybe bearable) but not for the full structure. As you have mentioned there may be some issue with indexing in the table.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the index is missing then, since you're talking about max 15 levels, meaning cte should max do 15 loops or so. You should post your "real" structure, if you want more specific help me thinks